# GD:Graph has no output when DBI connection is made

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi, gd-graph

I'm working on a small server to feed pages containing data relevant to my home automation setup. I've got a database full of sensor data that I can successfully query and output to an graph image if I un-comment the section at the bottom. I can also get this to print a graph when accessing it through a browser as a cgi script by replacing the sqlite code with the manually created out1 and out2 that are commented out near the middle. The problem comes with trying to put it all together and view the graphed sqlite data as a cgi script in a browser. I've narrowed the problem down to the connect code. When i add it to an otherwise working script you get no image output; but I know the the connect code works. It has to be something obvious but I just can't find it. Thoughts?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI ':standard';
use DBI;
use GD::Graph::lines;
use strict;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(          
    "dbi:SQLite:dbname=/root/distancetest", 
    "",
    "",
    { RaiseError => 1}
) or die $!;


my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM distance");
$sth->execute();

my $row;
my @data;
my @out1;
my @out2;

while ($row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref()) {
    push(@out1, @$row[0]);
    push(@out2, @$row[1]);
}
#@out1 = (1,2,3,4,5);
#@out2 = (1,2,3,4,5);

$data[0] = \@out1;
$data[1] = \@out2;

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();

my $skip = int ((@data * 8)/(600-50) + 1);

my $mygraph = GD::Graph::lines->new(600, 300);
$mygraph->set(
    x_label     => 'Timestamp',
    y_label     => 'cm',
    title       => 'Distance measuted at time',
    line_types  => [1],
    line_width  => 2,
    x_labels_vertical => 1,
    x_label_skip => $skip,
    dclrs       => ['blue'],
) or warn $mygraph->error;

$mygraph->set_legend_font(GD::gdMediumBoldFont);
$mygraph->set_legend('sensor1');
my $myimage = $mygraph->plot(\@data) or die $mygraph->error;

print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";
#open(OUTPUT, ">$0.png") or die "Can't open $0.png: $!\n";
#print OUTPUT $myimage->png();
print $myimage->png;
```

Comment: What do you have in your error log? Also you can try to add `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` to see what's wrong. The problem is not related to DBI or GD::Graph but file system's persmissions instead.

Comment: Huh, I was looking for a way to get it to print errors. Thanks. As expected it says it's unable to open the database. Doesn't any anything beyond that though. Everything is set up as owned by root and I suppose lighttpd has lower access. I'll start looking there. As for the error log; I'm still finding my way around. I just reinstalled arch on a pogoplug and it now uses systemd. New waters.

Comment: It really was that simple. I set the /srv/http to be owned by http(and moved the database out of the root home) and it works perfectly. I'm new to asking a question here but I assume if you post as an answer I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find what's wrong with your code you can add this line:

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```